# What is the server path for standalone ORDS running Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, server, oracle-apex, oracle-ords, utl-http

I am trying to put a php file on a folder and call it using UTL_HTTP.REQUEST from SQL and in APEX. I used xampp software to host it and it works. So I was wondering if there is a way to put in a file "somewhere" in ORDS or Database directory so I could access it in the same way? Or is there any way to access a file from URL like `"localhost:8080/ords/[my folder and file name]"`

My Config:

Database 19c

APEX 22.1

ORDS 21.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure basic *file* access by configuring a document root, but this is file access not Web CGI style components like PHP, Pything, Perl etc etc.

If it is just file access you control that via the standalone.properties file

```
standalone.doc.root=/u01/files/standalone/doc_root
```

Comment: The php file I have contains an API call which retrieves data from a HTTP (not HTTPS) website. As UTL_HTTP requires the SSL certificate validation, we had to bypass it by that php file (which I am not very familiar with so forgive me for my amateur take on this). I was wondering whether I could do something like that on my local machine with standalone ORDS.

Comment: Nope. You'd need to use (say) Tomcat for that. Tim has a nice installation guide for ORDS on Tomcat https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-installation-on-tomcat-22-onward